# Does Unity Master Server always try to connect to 67.225.180.24?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using unity 4.6
I have following code

```
    void Start() {
        Debug.Log ("OnStart");
        MasterServer.ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    }

    private void StartServer()
    {
        Network.InitializeServer(4, 25000, !Network.HavePublicAddress ());
        MasterServer.RegisterHost(typeName, gameName);
    }
```

I have MasterServer running on localhost.

At first it's called Start(). It's one of MonoBehaviour methods, so at start of the game I set ipAdress to localhost, then by click on the button I call StartServer(). At this moment ipAdress property equals to '127.0.0.1', but at unity console I see following:

```
    The connection request to 67.225.180.24:50005 failed. Are you sure the server can be connected to?
```

In console of my local MasterServer I see that there is new new game registered, and I can see this game when I call MasterServer.RequestHostList(gameType)

So does it means that unity always try to connect to unity's master server first? or did I miss something?

Comment: The Master Server is a free Server that Unity Provides. No it does not always connect to 67.225.180.24:50005 it changes it port to an available port. 

But yes, it always connect first to the MasterServer if you check the MasterServer Class. It has a property of ipAddress where you can change it.

This is a ready property call if you know how to setup your own MasterServer that implements Registration of the Game.

F

Answer (score 1):

NO, it does not always connect to 67.225.180.24:50005 because it will change it's port value to an available one.

MasterServer is free provided by Unity. But if you go to definition of MasterServer class, you will see that there is a property called ipAddress where
you can get or set it. Meaning it is not protected.

You can alter it by using the MasterServer.ipAddress as it is a static class.
this is made ready for those who have their own MasterServer ready and can implement Registration of game and gametype.

If you change it to 127.0.0.1 it will fail, if you don't have a master server.
However, if you try to register without an internet to the default Ip, it will use your current device IP address instead.

If you use a mobile device. Without an internet. Meaning Local MasterServer hosting. You won't be able to host the game, unless you use hot spot for another device to connect to you. Before they can see your game.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but my problem was that I've change ipAdress property to localhost, then I try to connect to local MasterServer and while connecting in Unity console I see message that it fails to connect to Unity's MasterServer. And after that it works fine with my local MasterServer.   Sorry for not clearly formulated question, I've edit it,